# Adding preinclude header file to Eclipse CDT C project

Tags: c, build, include, eclipse-cdt

I'm importing a C project to Eclipse CDT which has a preinclude header file. I want to know if there's an option to preinclude the file in the projects settings, The projects doesn't compile because of unresolved defines, that needs to be defined in the start.
does anyone encountered this before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've seen such problems several times.

If your project doesn't compile, you'll have to change the compiler options, since the compiler needs to know about the file. It depends on your compiler, though, since this is not a C feature.

Answer (score 0):

If it is that CDT do not find the files that are "preincluded" by your compiler, then you can fix that by creating build configuration. You do that by clicking on properties/C/C++ Build/Settings/Tool Settings/Cross GCC Compiler/Includes and then add the file you want to be preincluded.